# chef-shell --solo Chef::Exceptions::PrivateKeyMissing

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-solo

I am building a recipe where I'm trying to debug how the attributes are being set, but when I execute chef-shell it gives me errors about missing /etc/chef/client.pem, from what I can tell those are generated by chef server, as I'm running in --solo mode shouldn't it skip the requirement for such things?  Or am I using chef-shell improperly?

```
chef-shell --solo -c debug/solo.rb -j debug/nodes.json

loading configuration: debug/solo.rb
Session type: solo
Loading...done.

This is the chef-shell.
 Chef Version: 11.14.6
 http://www.opscode.com/chef
 http://docs.opscode.com/

run `help' for help, `exit' or ^D to quit.

Ohai2u bob@MSIGS70stealth.thalhalla.net!
chef > roles.all
[2014-11-10T13:15:08-06:00] WARN: Failed to read the private key /etc/chef/client.pem: #<Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /etc/chef/client.pem>
Chef::Exceptions::PrivateKeyMissing: I cannot read /etc/chef/client.pem, which you told me to use to sign requests!
        from /home/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/chef-11.14.6/lib/chef/http/authenticator.rb:78:in `rescue in load_signing_key'
        from /home/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/chef-11.14.6/lib/chef/http/authenticator.rb:68:in `load_signing_key'
        from /home/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/chef-11.14.6/lib/chef/http/authenticator.rb:38:in `initialize'
        from /home/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/chef-11.14.6/lib/chef/rest.rb:66:in `new'
        from /home/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/chef-11.14.6/lib/chef/rest.rb:66:in `initialize'
        from /home/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/chef-11.14.6/lib/chef/search/query.rb:34:in `new'
        from /home/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/chef-11.14.6/lib/chef/search/query.rb:34:in `initialize'
        from /home/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/chef-11.14.6/lib/chef/role.rb:184:in `new'
        from /home/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/chef-11.14.6/lib/chef/role.rb:184:in `list'
        from /home/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/chef-11.14.6/lib/chef/shell/model_wrapper.rb:82:in `list_objects'
        from /home/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/chef-11.14.6/lib/chef/shell/model_wrapper.rb:50:in `all'
        from (irb):1
        from /home/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/chef-11.14.6/lib/chef/shell.rb:75:in `block in start'
        from /home/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/chef-11.14.6/lib/chef/shell.rb:74:in `catch'
        from /home/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/chef-11.14.6/lib/chef/shell.rb:74:in `start'
        from /home/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/gems/chef-11.14.6/bin/chef-shell:37:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/chef-shell:23:in `load'
        from /home/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/chef-shell:23:in `<main>'
        from /home/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks2.1:15:in `eval'
        from /home/bob/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks2.1:15:in `<main>'chef >
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That method just isn't supported in solo mode. You can see in the code that is just calls either search or `chef_server_rest` directly.